# wake up from suspend to ram problem

Tags: 12.04, suspend, wakeup

I have very strange problem. After suspending to ram notebook doesn't wakes up, only leds and fan switches on, no HDD activity and display stays off(without backlights-completly off).

If I press numlock- led doesn't switches, all buttons are not warkable.
I have installed uswsusp and tryed to use s2ram, but result is exactly similar.
I tryed to remove fglrx, but useless.

I have HP Pavilion dv6 2055er with Ubuntu 12.04 on board and:
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RV710 [Mobility Radeon HD 4500/5100 Series]

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this mate -
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1978290

Good luck! :)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thank you, but useless.. This workaround helps when "the screen remains lit but black when you wake your machine" but I have no backlight on totally black screen.